# How is possible that only microsoft softwares can't see the internet?

Tags: microsoft-edge, internet-connection, cortana

How is possible that only a few softwares can't see the internet?

Everything connects to the internet, except Windows Store and Microsoft Edge

The question is why? Look at the print screen from my dual monitor desktop.

Softwares that are connected to the internet:
-Firefox
-Chrome
-ping (to google and to my router)
-Microsoft Internet Explorer
-Spotify
-Everything else

Software that can't see the internet:
-Cortana
-Microsoft Edge
-Windows Store

Comment: Did you check internet options (e.g. proxy settings) in internet explorer?

Comment: It's worth noting that all of the above all use the same network stack - whereas Firefox/Chrome, etc have their own built in - so if there is an issue with WinInet (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx) then all of these will be affected. Additionally, ensure that these applications have the capability to get through your firewall if you have it turned on via defender.